# Copy one list to another list

Tags: erlang

I am stuck at some basic recursion since this language is completely new for me, I want to copy integers from one list to another.

This is what I have:

```
cpy_list(L) -> cpy_list(L, []).
cpy_list([], Acc) -> Acc;
```

could somebody show me how a working solution can look like?

Comment: There is no point in copying a list, like @BlackMamba says. Since data is immutable, a simple reference the the existing list is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more clause for the`cpy_list/2`

```
cpy_list(L) -> cpy_list(L, []). % Starting condition 

cpy_list([H|T], Acc) -> cpy_list(T, Acc ++ [H]); % take the first element and add to Acc
cpy_list([], Acc) -> Acc.
```

Of course, it is not an ideal solution because it is not efficient. See note here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html

And since variables are immutable in erlang, I doubt there is any point in copying a list.

Comment: +1 For "And since variables are immutable in erlang, I doubt there is any point in copying a list.". I can't think of any reason to want to copy a list. Anything you do to transform a list will produce an (altered) copy of it!

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, assigning a variable into a new one is "copying" the content from the on to the other. (no pointers!)

So you don't need a special function for it.

```
TheList = [1,2,3,4,5].
CpyList = TheList.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cpy_list(L) -> cpy_list(L, []).

cpy_list([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
cpy_list([H|T], Acc) ->
    cpy_list(T, [H|Acc]).
```

Here is the code, you can use [Tail-recursive](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#id64339)

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang since all data is immutiable there is no point in copying a list. Anything you do to manipulate the list will produce an altered copy of the original list. If you did want to copy a list it would be as simple as running:

```
List = [1,2,3],
NewList = lists:map(fun(X) -> X end, List).
```

Because `lists:map/2` will always returns a new list this will work! You could just have easily have performed your alterations on the original list with `map/2` and it would have returned a completely new list.

Answer (score 0):

Once can also use a list comprehension:

```
ListCopy = [Entry || Entry <- ListOriginal]
```